# Trying to use Flask to display query results using Pything

Tags: python, sql-server, flask

I'm trying the below code to display the results of a simple query in a web browser but am getting a 500 error

```
from flask import Flask
import sql_class

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    try:
        sql = sql_class.executeScriptsFromFile
        result = sql("My random file path") 
        print "it works"
        return result
    except: 
        print "you broke it"
        return "hello world"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The sql_class is a custom class I use on a regular base to connect to our SQL server DB and run a script from the given file path. I can copy the code outside the function and print the results to the console window just fine, but for some reason it breaks down within the flask function

Comment: What is the query returning? (What is the value of the `result` variable?)

Comment: When you set ``app.debug = True`` what does it show in your browser?

Comment: @ShamilKMuhammed  The query is effectively "select cities from table1 group by cities". It's got 8 records in the answer set.

Comment: @nephlm this is the error message TypeError: 'list' object is not callable. I'm thinking that for some reason Flask can't use my class / connection string. But honestly no idea why

Comment: @John what do you expect to see in the browser?

Comment: @ShamilKMuhammed. I'd love to just see a list of the cities displayed IE "Boise, New York, LA, etc. etc.". I'm just trying to learn a web framework for a larger project I've got in mind. Step 1 was retrieve and display information from an existing SQL server database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query returns a list, You shouldn't return lists as response in Flask.

Try making your list a string, like this:

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    try:
        sql = sql_class.executeScriptsFromFile
        result = sql("My random file path") 
        print "it works"
        return str(result)
    except: 
        print "you broke it"
        return "hello world"
```

Or encode it into json:

```
import json

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    try:
        sql = sql_class.executeScriptsFromFile
        result = sql("My random file path") 
        print "it works"
        return json.dumps(result)
    except: 
        print "you broke it"
        return "hello world"
```

Or make it a comma separated string like this:

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    try:
        sql = sql_class.executeScriptsFromFile
        result = sql("My random file path") 
        print "it works"
        return ", ".join(result)
    except: 
        print "you broke it"
        return "hello world"
```

I suggest taking the Flask tutorial